# How to compute $\int_{\{|y|=R\}} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n} \sigma (dy)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let $R>0$, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Then, how can I compute $\int_{\{|y|=R\}}\frac{1}{|x-y|^n} \sigma (dy)$ ? Here, $\sigma$ is a surface Lebesgue measure on $\{|y|=R\}$

I guess that I use polar coordinate. I know the case $x=0$, but I cannot compute in the case.

Comment: Do you mean the invariant measure or any measure supported on the sphere?

Comment: Lebesgu measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$